# Trying to create a Match and Copy function for VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to make a code but unable to complete it that how to match `G9` value with `ColE:E` as i described below.

There are two Sheets in Excel file which name are `Sheet1` and `Sheet4`. `Sheet1` has Data and that data will pasted into `Sheet4` after matching the value.

Sheet4.Range("G9") = [image] code will match that value into Sheet1.Range("E:E") =

[image]

If matches code will copy the yellow highlighted data till end of the column and paste into Sheet4.range("G11") as transpose.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

my code

```
Sub myfunc()


Dim Cell As Range

With Sheet1
      For Each Cell In .Range("E1:E" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)
        If Cell.Value = Sheet4.Range("G9") Then

       'looking for method
        End If
    Next Cell
End With



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy/Transpose with Match

- Adjust the values in the constants section and double-check the worksheets.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub myCopyTranspose()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const sFirstCell As String = "E7"
    Const sCopyFirstColumn As String = "D"
    Const dCriteriaCell As String = "G9"
    Const dFirstCell As String = "G11"
    
    ' Define Source Search (Column) Range and Row Offset.
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim RowOffset As Long
    With Sheet1.Range(sFirstCell)
        Set cel = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If cel Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data
        Set rg = .Resize(cel.Row - .Row + 1)
        RowOffset = .Row - 1
    End With
    
    ' Retrieve Criteria.
    Dim cValue As Variant: cValue = Sheet4.Range(dCriteriaCell).Value
    If IsError(cValue) Then Exit Sub ' error value
    If Len(cValue) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' empty or blank
    cValue = CStr(cValue)
    
    ' Find a match of Criteria in Source Search Range.
    Dim cMatch As Variant
    cMatch = Application.Match("*" & cValue & "*", rg, 0)
    If IsError(cMatch) Then Exit Sub ' no match
    
    ' Define Source Copy (Row) Range.
    With Sheet1.Cells(cMatch + RowOffset, sCopyFirstColumn)
        Set cel = Nothing
        Set cel = .Resize(, .Worksheet.Columns.Count - .Column + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If cel Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data
        Set rg = .Resize(, cel.Column - .Column + 1)
    End With
    
    ' Copy/Transpose Source Copy (Row) Range to Destination (Column) Range.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    rg.Copy
    Sheet4.Range(dFirstCell).PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteAll, _
        Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Data transferred.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```

Comment: There is one thing which needs to be change if it can be that is, Data will be copied from Col"H" to last Col"" then will paste into as transpose.

Comment: Just replace `D` with `H`, `sCopyFirstColumn` being the first column the data is copied from.